# 5.7.1. unable to relay, is this the web server or the exchange server?

Tags: c#, email, iis, smtpclient

im getting a 5.7.1 error when my app tries to send to an external recipient. the error doesnt say where the source comes from, is it the IIS server that cannot relay or is it my exchange server?

For testing I make it send one email internally and one externally. the internal one always comes through, but the external fails, im just tryign to find out where i need to be looking for errors, the exchange server or the IIS server (the IP used below is the exchange server)

Thanks

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
var SMTPCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "Pass", "Domain");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = SMTPCredentials;
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Host = "192.168.1.115";
```

Comment: I would look at the credentials you're sending to the external exchange server.

Comment: So the relay message means its the exchange server not the webserver?

Comment: Yes.  5.7.1 indicates that the user email client failed to authenticate on the mail server.

Comment: ok i reset the credentials, i guess these were causing errors! whoops! now i get {"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated"} im working on this now so hopfully will fix soon, thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you got any hints for this one? everything I google is coming up trumps...

Comment: Ive done it, needed to send to port 587 not 25

Answer (score -1):

Two things

Incorrect credentials where used
needed to use port 587 instead of 25

Comment: did you down vote for counting, sentence structure, or relevance?  ... or is it actually 2 things